# Why won't my HTML file find my javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML file that I am trying to link to a javascript file.  Both are in C:\Users\Me\Test
(so there's C:\Users\Me\Test\Test.html and C:\Users\Me\Test\test.js)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SoundCloud API</title>
    <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="genre">EDM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="genre">classical</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="genre">soundtrack</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Javascript:

```
function playSomeSound(genre){
    SC.get('/tracks', {
        genres: genre,
        bpm: {
            from: 100
        }
    }, function(tracks){
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*49);
        SC.oEmbed(tracks[random].uri, {auto_play: true}, document.getElementById('target'));
    });
}

window.onload = function(){
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: '*******'
    });

    var menuLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('genre');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++){
        var menuLink = menuLinks[i];
        menuLink.onclick = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            playSomeSound(menuLink.innerHTML);
        };
    }
};
```

(Note the Client ID is actually the correct ID in the code.)

The HTML correctly displays the three links, but nothing happens when I click them.  Am I missing something?

For what it's worth, I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TuqjGxosrc) tutorial.  Thanks for any ideas/tips!

Edit: Note, when the HTML page loads, I can View Source, then click the "test.js" and it does actually load the Javascript source...so it is seeing the JavaScript correctly, leading me to think there's something up with the Javascript itself...

**Edit 2:**
I was able to get the editor I'm using (SublimeText 2) to build javascript, and get this error:

> function (tracks){
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

meaning it's not expecting the "(" after "function"?...maybe that helps?

**Edit 3:**
Okay, I've been searching around and was able to get a different error, by adding {} around the BPM:

```
function playSomeSound(genre){
    SC.get('/tracks', {genres: genre}, {bpm: { from: 100 }},
        function(tracks){
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*49);
            SC.oEmbed(tracks[random].uri, {auto_play: true}, document.getElementById('target'));
        });
    console.log(genre);
}


window.onload = function(){
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: "6e6078f1408f62443f757b4c34d55e12"
    });

    var menuLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('genre');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++){
        var menuLink = menuLinks[i];
        menuLink.onclick = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            playSomeSound(menuLink.innerHTML);
        };
    }
};
```

Now, I get the error:

> window.onload = function(){
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Is there an error message in the JavaScript console?

Comment: <script src="/test.js"></script> ??

Comment: @DyllenJamesOwens - No, that would be referring to the root.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 essentially if he's putting it as just test.js. He's clearly hosting everything from the root. Kind of would make sense.

Comment: @DyllenJamesOwens - He explicitly said everything is in `C:\Users\Me\Test` so.... And also everything is in the same level so no `/` is needed.

Comment: Make sure you know where your /ROOT file path is it looks to me that you need to add / backlash [/test.js]

Comment: I added a "/" before "test.js" and still, nothing happens.  And no, there's no error in the console :/ .

Comment: Have you turned off Javascript in your browser? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Uooo yeah, Javascript is enabled.

Comment: You could "debug" it. You never answered the question about whether there are any errors in the console. Are there? Do you know how to view the console? Then put an breakpoint on the first line of the `window.onload` function. Etc. etc.

Comment: @torazaburo I am writing this with a text editor essentially (SublimeText 2), and I can't build properly to see the console.  Do you have a Java IDE to recommend?

Comment: Press F12 in your browser.

Comment: @torazaburo ah okay - I get " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (".  I edited my first post and it looks like it's occurring around "function(tracks)" ?

Comment: Do you get the `window is undefined` error when running in the browser? That would be most odd. I've reviewed your code and there are no visible syntax errors. Please run your code in the browser, not in some ST environment (don't know how that works). Open up devtools and view the console. Perhaps you will see an error in `SC.initialize` or some other run-time error. Impossible to say without more information or context.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for your help - Now, (I don't know why) but I'm getting a different error: In my folder, I open the HTML document in my browser (Chrome), and try to run.  I open the console via F12, and get this line in the console:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=soundtrack&client_id=6e6078f1408f62443f757b4c34d55e12&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.sdk.js:1 window.SC.SC.Helper.merge._xhrRequest"

Comment: Right. You finally found the problem. You cannot normally do an ajax request (which is what this is, being done internally in ` SC.oEmbed` most likely) to another domain. You have several options, but the topic is too broad to explain in a comment. You may be able to use a technique called "jsonp", or proxy the request through your own server. Please do a web search for CORS.

Comment: @torazaburo Ah! Okay, will do thank you very much! Related question - do you know why then it wouldn't be mentioned in that tutorial video? That seems like something rather important to note.  ...but anyways, thanks for your help and I've got some learning to do!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is not coming from you. The javascript file has been correctly loaded (try to add this code :

```
function playSomeSound(genre){
    SC.get('/tracks', {
    genres: genre,
    bpm: {
        from: 100
    }
}, function(tracks){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*49);
    SC.oEmbed(tracks[random].uri, {auto_play: true}, document.getElementById('target'));
});
}

window.onload = function(){
SC.initialize({
    client_id: '*******'
});

    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
var menuLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('genre');
for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++){
    var menuLink = menuLinks[i];
    menuLink.onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        playSomeSound(menuLink.innerHTML);
    };
}
};
```

in your javascript file

and the html :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SoundCloud API</title>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="genre">EDM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="genre">classical</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="genre">soundtrack</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This tutorial was made in 2012 (it's a long long time ago), maybe the script is out of date or something like that.

Comment: Howdy, I tried that (literally putting the alert right under the closing }); and nothing happens...

Comment: Added an alert for "debug", this worked fine for me. Also make sure they are in the same directory.

Comment: I changed the Javascript to what you have and the Alert Box launched!  However, the Soundcloud stuff still doesn't work... Hmm.

Comment: If you want use the soundcloud sdk you need a client_id. Here a link where you can sign up : https://soundcloud.com/signup Also don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: I have a client ID, I just substituted it with "****" for the sake of this.  (Is it okay to share client IDs? I thought no which is why I put asterisks...). I get this issue with a Client ID correctly in place... :/

Answer (score 0):

You should load all your JavaScript files at the very end of the body, just before the `</body>` tag. This will make JavaScript run more predictably and reliably and is likely the cause of the problem here. There are very few circumstances when you'll want the JavaScript to be called anywhere else.

Comment: I changed the two <script> lines to be right before </body> and it didn't change anything...

Comment: @Goose In what way might it be  "likely the cause of the problem here"? If this is a diagnostic question, or an idea, it should be a comment, not an answer.